# list js pagination click last button shows last row using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 14 row in my collection,

The limit is 7. So, Each page I can see 7.

I have four buttons First, Last, Next, Prev. The problem with the last button. If I click the last button, It shows last row (Only one row). It should show 7.

```js
var monkeyList = new List('test-list', {
  valueNames: ['name'],
  page: 7,
  pagination: true
});

 $('.text-center').append('<div class="btn-next"> > </div><div class="btn-last"> >| </div>');
      $('.text-center').prepend('<div class="btn-first"> |< </div><div class="btn-prev"> < </div>');
      
      $('.btn-next').on('click', function(){
         $('.pagination .active').next().trigger('click');
      })
      $('.btn-prev').on('click', function(){
         $('.pagination .active').prev().trigger('click');
      })
      $('.btn-first').on('click', function(){
         monkeyList.show(1,7);
      })
      $('.btn-last').on('click', function(){
         monkeyList.show(monkeyList.size(),7);
      })
```

```css
.pagination li {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:5px;
}
.btn-last, .btn-first, .btn-prev, .btn-next, .pagination li a {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #424242;
    padding: 2px 10px;
    margin: 2px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #e0e0e0;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 35px;
    background-color: #565656;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/list.js/1.5.0/list.min.js"></script>
  
  <div id="test-list">
    <input type="text" class="search" />
    <ul class="list">
      <li><p class="name">Guybrush Threepwood</p></li>
      <li><p class="name">Elaine Marley</p></li>
      <li><p class="name">LeChuck</p></li>
      <li><p class="name">Stan</p></li>
      <li><p class="name">Voodoo Lady</p></li>
      <li><p class="name">Herman Toothrot</p></li>
      <li><p class="name">Meathook</p></li>
      <li><p class="name">Carla</p></li>
      <li><p class="name">Otis</p></li>
      <li><p class="name">Rapp Scallion</p></li>
      <li><p class="name">Rum Rogers Sr.</p></li>
      <li><p class="name">Men of Low Moral Fiber</p></li>
      <li><p class="name">Murray</p></li>
      <li><p class="name">Cannibals</p></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="text-center">
      <ul class="pagination"></ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

My Working Example here [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/ashok-charu/pen/ZRYgGQ)

Thanx

Comment: It would be more helpfull if you could provide us with a working example of the problem

Comment: @AshokCharu Your code snippet doesn't work. What is `List`? What is your initial markup?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen My working example added please check

Comment: @AshokCharu try this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mKyNRQ

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen If I have more rows also, It should Work. I checked with your example, With 14 rows, it's working, If i have 15 rows, It's not Working

Comment: @YuryTarabanko My working example added please check

Comment: @AshokCharu is this how it shall work then ? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MXwgJr

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen given example 16 rows, In the last page, It should show 2 row(7+7,+2=16) but it shows 6. please check

Comment: @AshokCharu try this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aKOoGM

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I checked With 14 records When I click last button, It shows Empty page

Comment: Don't ever use JS / jQuery methods on stylistic classes like `.text-center`. You clearly don't want that. Also don't use `>` as arrows in HTML, rather the escaped `&gt;` or `&lt;`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yeah ok, I will change that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
  $('.btn-last').on('click', function(){
    var total = monkeyList.size(),
        page = (total % 7) || 7, // the reminder or full page
        start = total - page + 1 ; // calculate last page first item

        monkeyList.show(start, 7);
  })
```

[Working example](https://codepen.io/tarabyte/pen/MXwgBX)

[Docs](http://listjs.com/api/#show)

> `show(i, page)` Shows `page` number of items from `i`.